# Error handling in AngularJS http get then construct

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

How can I handle an HTTP error, e.g. 500, when using the AngularJS "http get then" construct (promises)?

```
$http.get(url).then(
    function(response) {
        console.log('get',response)
    }
)
```

Problem is, for any non 200 HTTP response, the inner function is not called.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You need to add an additional parameter:

```
$http.get(url).then(
    function(response) {
        console.log('get',response)
    },
    function(data) {
        // Handle error here
    })
```

Comment: Note also that 'response' object above has: data, status, headers, config, statusText.  The 'data' object above has: data, status, config, statusText.  (There are special rules about whether statusText is passed - browsers, mobile or not, web server etc.)

Comment: Also note: `data.config.url` contains the full **url + params**
, in case you passed params next to url

Comment: I don't know but it is not working for my case. Always the response code is executed.

Answer (score 59):

You can make this bit more cleaner by using:

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('get',response)
    })
    .catch(function (data) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Similar to @this.lau_ answer, different approach.

Comment: I'd totally go for this solution.

Comment: it must be accepted answer, because `.error()` method does not work with 500 errors! Please accept.

Comment: Best solution after `success` & `remove` is removed in v1.6.0

Comment: **NOTE** that `.catch` also executes if `.then` has internal error (like calling non-existing method) while `.then(success, error)` will handle error only if request itself fails

Answer (score 14):

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http.get(url).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
```

Replace successCallback and errorCallback with your functions.

Edit: Laurent's answer is more correct considering he is using `then`. Yet I'm leaving this here as an alternative for the folks who will visit this question.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this does not do the same thing as Laurent's answer. `.then()` returns a promise. `.success()` and `.error()` do not.

Comment: @james-brewer: To be more accurate, `.then()` returns a **new** promise. `.success()` and `.error()` do not, they both return the original promise provided by `get(url)`.

Comment: It's important also to keep in mind that `success` and `error` callbacks for $http api will be deprecated.

Comment: Also `success` and `error` also removed in v1.6.0, can't be used anymore.

Comment: Note also that the documentation says "deprecated" but success() and error() are actually completely "removed"; don't be fooled.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle server errors globally, you may want to register an interceptor service for $httpProvider:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            // do something on error
            if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                return responseOrNewPromise
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

**Docs**: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: I think you have made a mistake there. To handle response errors you need to create a response interceptor not a request interceptor as you have done.

Comment: The interceptor for angular is both request and response as of 1.1.x.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function sendRequest(method, url, payload, done){

        var datatype = (method === "JSONP")? "jsonp" : "json";
        $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                dataType: datatype,
                data: payload || {},
                cache: true,
                timeout: 1000 * 60 * 10
        }).then(
            function(res){
                done(null, res.data); // server response
            },
            function(res){
                responseHandler(res, done);
            }
        );

    }
    function responseHandler(res, done){
        switch(res.status){
            default: done(res.status + ": " + res.statusText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not really work with the above. So this might help someone.

```
$http.get(url)
  .then(
    function(response) {
        console.log('get',response)
    }
  ).catch(
    function(response) {
    console.log('return code: ' + response.status);
    }
  )
```

See also the [`$http response` parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns).