# Servlet send 400 error with data

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I want my `servlet` to return error code with data, so client can point out to the user what is wrong with the request.
In case of `exception` when the data is invalid:

```
catch (UnvaildInputException UIE) {
            UnvaildCodes unvaildCode = UIE.getUnvaildCode(); //code 1 for example
            System.out.println(unvaildCode.getKey() + "-" + unvaildCode.getValue()); //prints error key-val
            System.out.println(unvaildCode.getValue());
            response.getWriter().print(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST +":"+unvaildCode.getValue()); //trying to write a string as data
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); //400
        }
```

Now on client side(`angularjs`) I am trying to access the data:

```
httpService.sendPost(vm.details, '/some/url').then(function (response){
        $log.log(response);
        $log.log(response.data);
});
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at formDirectiveJS.js:91
    at angular.min.js:126
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:140)
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:137)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:141)
    at g (angular.min.js:93)
    at t (angular.min.js:98)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.min.js:99)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the error in an error handler, not the success handler.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458437/1842905

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('get',response)
})
.catch(function (data) {
    // Handle error here
});
```