# AngularJS: How to detect if there is not a response in $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have this code in AngularJS:

```
$http({
  url: my_url,
  method: "GET",
  data: null,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "my-token": "mytoken",

  }
}).then(function(response, err) {
  console.log(response)
  console.log(err)
});
```

When the URL is correct and the status is `200`, the response is displayed with status `200`. But I want now to test with a wrong Url, then nothing is displayed, neither response nor error, so how to detect if there is no response?

Comment: there is always a error code or status

Comment: Use `errorCallback` of `then()` method i.e. `.then(function (response, err) {
                                               }, function(response){ //do stuff}
                  );`

Comment: **refer to this url** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080146/error-handling-in-angularjs-http-get-then-construct

Comment: did you try to use all of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559341/using-success-error-finally-catch-with-promises-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

By reading the [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you can handle errors inside your error callback function. Also take a look at this [HTTP Status Code list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Any **4xx** status code e.g. **404 - not found** will end inside the *errorCallback* function. You are also be able to handle the HTTP status by accessing `response.status` inside your callback functions.

**Please note** that there is always a response / HTTP Status code while performing an HTTP-Request.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b971fxv0/)**

Comment: Also there is no response displaying on successCallback and errorCallback when the url is wrong !

Comment: @user2285831 sure there is a response (**404 - not found**). Take a look at the demo fiddle. Please tell me the URL you try to access.

Comment: It's a url of a file in my server

Comment: @user2285831 open your browser debugger - in network tab what is your server responding when you try to access this file via `$http`?

Comment: yes with a wrong url i have this
Request URL:https://www.myurlwrong.com
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: `Referrer Policy` is an response header. In that way you actually recive a response. This request also should result in an error callback with status code `-1`.

Comment: this is only on network in the browser, but there is no response !

Answer (score 0):

`then` takes two functions as parameters. First is called for `success` and Second is called for `error`. This is called `promise`.

Use following code to catch error:

```
.then(function(response) {
    // Success
}, function(error) {
    // Error
})
```

Comment: have displayed `error` in console? What kind of URL you are using?

Comment: it's a url of a file in my server

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
    url: my_url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "my-token": "mytoken",

    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.data);
});
```

Add a function as second parameter to `.then()` will track error cases for http calls.

Comment: can you try by removing `data:null`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with this line, it should be removed 
"my-token": "mytoken",
Thank you !

Comment: **This answer is wrong**. This is nothing depending on your headers as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ca074sgm/ You will get a **-1** HTTP-Status once a timeout hit in. There is **ALWAYS a response**.